# angular2 ngif selected show required form

Tags: html, angular

I'm new to angular2

I want to create a function that when user choose an option the required form wil be show.

[image: This is my interface]

This is my `html code`

```
<label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="select">Zone</label>
<div class="col-md-9">
<select class="form-control" id="select" name="select" size="1">
<option *ngFor="let obj of zone"  value={{obj.id}} ngDefaultControl>
 {{obj?.name}}</option>
</select>
 </div>
```

Let's say a user chooses Zone 1, then a form for Zone 1 appears. If a user selects Zone 2, then a form for Zone 2 appears. And so on. How can I create those functions in Angular2? I want the form to appeared in the same html page.

Comment: Where you want to show it? in a part of the component? modal dialog?

Comment: @Sam in the same `html` page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:
- Delare a property in component class to hold selected zone
- Then use ngIf base on above property

```
<label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="select">
<div *ngIf="selectedid==1">
Zone1
</div>
<div *ngIf="selectedid==2">
Zone2
</div>
</label>
<div class="col-md-9">
<select class="form-control" id="select" [(ngModel)]="selectedid" name="select" size="1">
<option *ngFor="let obj of zone"  value={{obj.id}} ngDefaultControl>
 {{obj?.name}}</option>
</select>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this with switch cases like below.
My HTML file:

```
<label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="select">Zone</label>
<div class="col-md-9">
  <select class="form-control" id="select" name="select" size="1" [(ngModel)]="selected">
<option *ngFor="let obj of zone"  value={{obj.id}} ngDefaultControl>
 {{obj?.name}}</option>
</select>
</div>

<div [ngSwitch]="selected">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="1">
    <p>1st Form</p>
  </div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="2">
    <p>2nd Form</p>
  </div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="3">
    <p>3rd form</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

My TypeScript file

```
 zone:Array<Object>=[
    {id:1,name:"Name One"},
    {id:2,name:"Name Two"},
    {id:3,name:"Name Three"}
  ];
  selected:number=0;
```

Comment: @uetoaya happy to help you :)